# How can I arrange words into a shape to make a "word cloud" design?

Tags: text, visualization, text-wrap, word-cloud

I want to create a T-shirt to commemorate the tenth edition of a gaming convention and I had the idea to have the names of all the games that were played during the convention form a big roman numeral X.

I'm looking for a **free** program, app or plugin that allows me to insert chunks of text (the names of the games) and automatically sorts them to fit the shape as nicely as possible, without mixing the words in the same chunk (but if they continue on the same or on the following line it's ok).

Multi-directional words forming the shape is ok too but those usually make some words too small for the t-shirt printer.

Do you know a program that can create such a thing?

I can easily work with the image of an X or even a raster image.

Comment: You need to make searches for word clouds and word cloud generators, especially word cloud shapes.  I did some groundwork but I couldn't quickly retrieve anything.  You'll have to do some sifting to find what you're looking for.  The closest site to your request, tagxedo, is completely exclusive.  I didn't check to see if they offered a trial version or not.

Comment: You may find some useful ideas in the [Unusual shape of a textarea?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20728150/1672723) question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is

[**Taxedo**](http://www.tagxedo.com/)

...which would give you the ability to create tag-clouds and word clouds that looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

There are more than one solution. Two other online solutions with lots of polish are [*Wordle*](http://www.wordle.net/) (1) and [*WordItOut*](http://worditout.com/) (2). See also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud) for more resources. Some can generate code such as [html](http://tagcrowd.com/) or generate from a [query](http://cloud.yippy.com/) instead of a site/document. Some can export to *svg*.

There are surely many ways to do this. One way is with *Processing* (3). There is a library such as [*WordCram*](http://wordcram.org/) to fine tune some metrics which may not be exposed with the online tools. I generated the third example using a basic demo included therein. Exporting to svg, pdf etc. is also possible.

Comment: @user Thank you for the comment! Diversity is good as well as having a local solution. It helps decomposing OP's task(word cloud+layout). Even with raster as the words don't overlap then segments could be extracted(by hand or of course, programatically) and laid out. I would presume svg would allow for non destructive transforms etc. Cheers.