# Design wordcloud to fit custom shape with common software?

Tags: shapes, word-cloud

I want to design a cover page of a presentation with all the keywords arranged in such a way that they form a number (e.g. 7).

Here are some examples:
[image: Rethat]
[image: Bird] [image: Y]

My question is different from [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/how-can-i-arrange-words-into-a-shape-to-make-a-word-cloud-design) in that, I'm **not** looking for a free program, but rather looking for a way to do it in common programs such as Illustrator, Photoshop, or any other relevant ones.

Can you please point me to which is the best application to do this kind of design? And if possible the techniques to achieve the effect? Thank you very much.

Comment: Lots of manual tweaking then. In that case it doesn't matter what software you use just as long as your very industrious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it by hand. As far as I know, there is no function beyond [Taxedo](http://www.tagxedo.com/) (named in the question you referenced, and it's where your third example comes from) that will fully automatically create word-clouds in these complicated forms.

There is a place to start doing this manually, especially on the '7' example you give, and that's with InDesign's `Text Wrap` functionality. You can give any InDesign object a Text Wrap by selecting it and choosing settings in the `Text Wrap` panel (`Window > Text Wrap` or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Control/Option</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>).

[image: Text Wrap panel in InDesign]

I'd advise to go for the third option: 'wrap around object shape'. This will create a border around your shape where text will not flow. If you then place the object over a field full of text, it will repel all the text. You will have to manually readjust and replace the text for good legibility and flow, however.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar function and came across a decent YouTube video that shows how to do this in Illustrator.  good luck!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MeNVMfYbMBY

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD. Could you please expand on your answer to contain the main points of the instructions? Links go dead, and we aim to keep concrete information here.